# How to change label text in xamarin

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am relatively new to Xamarin forms. I have found out I am unable to change label text from the code behind. Normally I would do `myLabel.text = variable`. Does this work in Xamarin? If it does why does this code not change the text?

```
Label_ControlSW.Text = controlSW_Out;
            Label_BLESW.Text = bleSW_Out;
            Label_Mode.Text = mode_Out;
```

Xaml file

```
<Label x:Name="Label_ControlSW" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalOptions="Center"  VerticalOptions="Center" FontSize="17" TextColor="White"/>
                <Label x:Name="Label_BLESW" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalOptions="Center"  VerticalOptions="Center" FontSize="17" TextColor="#525252"/>
                <Label x:Name="Label_Mode"  Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalOptions="Center"  VerticalOptions="Center" FontSize="17" TextColor="White"/>
```

Comment: is textColor & background color  same?

Comment: No they are different colours

Comment: have u tried debugging whether values are there or not in variables

Comment: The values are there, the label text is also shown to have changed to the variable. The screen doesn't change.

Comment: Are you doing this while processing something big on the UI/main thread? If so, you may want to wait for it to finish, and then the UI will update.

Comment: The application has finished processing a ble connection and is just reading data and displaying it. There are no more processes running.

Comment: No the 'controlSW_Out' variable is set, but when the line 'Label_ControlSW.Text = controlSW_Out;' is run the label text does not update.

Comment: Perhaps you are updating controls that are no longer on screen if you see their properties update properly. Can you share a bit more about how the UI is displayed and how/when you are updating it?

Comment: this video has explained how we can use labels - https://youtu.be/-x7lTfr9zTA

Answer (score 23, accepted):

> Does this work in Xamarin?

Yes, it does.

> If it does why does this code not change the text?

Because the `Label` component is not bounded to the variable, it just gets its value when you did `Label_ControlSW.Text = controlSW_Out;` and no furthermore.

To make it works you have basically two choices:

**1. Set the value to the label on every change;**

There's no magic here. Just set the values or variables like [Ali Heikal's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52366708/8093394) suggests, but you must do that every time manually.

**2. Bind the page (View) to an Observable object (Model)**, then the view will listen to every change on your model and react to this (changing it's own `Text` value, for example).

I guess what you're intending to do is the second one. So you can create a public string property on your page's code-behind and bind the instance of your page to itself. Like this:

**XAML**

```
<Label Text="{Binding MyStringProperty}"
       .../>
```

**Code behind**

```
public partial class MyTestPage : ContentPage
{
    private string myStringProperty;
    public string MyStringProperty
    {
        get { return myStringProperty; }
        set 
        {
            myStringProperty = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(MyStringProperty)); // Notify that there was a change on this property
        }
    }
    
    public MyTestPage()
    {
        InitializeComponents();
        BindingContext = this;

        MyStringProperty = "New label text"; // It will be shown at your label
    }
}
```

You should take a look at [official docs about data bindings and MVVM pattern on XF](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/xaml-basics/data-bindings-to-mvvm) and if you're starting with Xamarin.Forms, I highly recommend you to follow the [official getting started guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/get-started/) that addresses each topic clear and deep enough to learn everything you need.

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 8):

Try initializing the `Text` value in XAML like the following:

```
<Label x:Name="YourLableName" Text="Initial Label"/>
```

Then access it in the code behind like the following:

```
YourLableName.Text = "Desired Name";
```

or

```
YourLableName.Text = variable;
```

Comment: The label just displays 'Initial Label' and not the variable

Answer (score 3):

In order to update the UI, you have to be on the UI thread. You would want to do something like:

```
 Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
 {
     Label_ControlSW.Text = controlSW_Out;
     Label_BLESW.Text     = bleSW_Out;
     Label_Mode.Text      = mode_Out;
 });
```

This will solve your problem, but as the others have stated in their answers, the Xamarin way to do this would be using [data binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/xaml-basics/data-bindings-to-mvvm) to update the view. The data binding will handle the UI update for you.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue. Try to **clean and build** your project after u make x:Name reference  in your view folder. Or you can do **Data** **binding**. By using this code

```
 <Label Text="{Binding MyProperty}" />
```

in **Xaml**. And in **ViewModel** class

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public string MyProperty { get; set; } = "My Label Text";
}
```

And in code behind just mention the **ViewModel** your using

```
this.BindingContext = new MyViewModel();
```

This is the correct approach. So try to use **MVVM** approach in your future of coding because this is the right approach.

Comment: Sorry, what is a view folder?

Comment: View folder is the xaml file. So whenever you are creating any reference in Xaml you need to build it so that reference can be used in Xaml.cs file.

Comment: In your code the reference is x:Name="Label_ControlSW" if u have to access this in your code behind you need to build it.

Comment: Not sure I understand what you are saying, I set the label text in the code then build it, and there are no errors. Should I set it a different way? I also tried to do the MVVM approach, but I am not sure how to set the label text to what I need from mainpage.xaml.cs, this is updated every two seconds.

Comment: If you are going to suggest MVVM you might want to show a working example. You would need an `INotifyPropertyChanged` implementation in your ViewModel also. I appreciate it adds complexity but without this would not work.

Answer (score 0):

There were a few reasons why this didn't work. I changed to the MVVM approach. This still had no effect but it was a better approach as was suggested. When debugging I noticed this line: I/Choreographer(16942): Skipped 31 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread. This was because I was doing too much on the main thread (ble connections) and it was just skipping the UI change. I had to restructure my code to perform more on different threads. Thanks for the help everyone.